# Impact of rerunning SharePoint 2010 Configuration Wizard

Tags: configuration-wizard

May I know what can be the impact of rerunning SharePoint 2010 configuration wizard? Would I lose any data or the entire central administration 2010? Please let me know what can be the impact since I do not want my farm or any web applications to lose any configuration or data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

why dont you backup your current system and then try re-run Configuration wizard, this way you will experience it and might learn some bits as well :)

however

> If you didn’t modify the default files of the SharePoint server, you
>   can run the Configuration Wizard.  The Default files including the
>   content below:
>
> 1. The default files locate in 12 folder(Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12);
> 2. SharePoint Content and Configuration Database;
> 3. The SharePoint registry information.
> 4. And so on.